# Trying to Connect Webcam to Visual Studio with OpenCV using C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, camera

I am relatively new to coding and have to takeover a C++ project from a colleague was dropped from a class.

So basically, I have to write and modify a C++ program using Visual Studio and OpenCV to connect a web camera to an interface. This interface displays the video output as well as if the camera is active. I was able to get the camera to be detected by the program, but I am having an issue with there being duplicate overlaying video outputs. The web camera that I am using is the J5create USB webcam [webcam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1w5F.png). The interface that appears when I run the code looks like this: [it just shows my iphone camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jajOW.png). It shows duplicate and overlapping video outputs, I just need it to be one concise video output. I've been running around trying to fix this issue on google etc to no avail. Can anyone help me fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


// Control IDs
const UINT_PTR ID_WEBCAM_STATUS = 1000;
const UINT_PTR ID_WEBCAM_IMAGE = 1020;
const UINT_PTR ID_KEYBOARD_STATUS = 1001;
const UINT_PTR ID_FINGERPRINT_STATUS = 1002;
const UINT_PTR ID_BARCODE_STATUS = 1003;
const UINT_PTR ID_HEADSET_STATUS = 1004;
const UINT_PTR ID_SPEAKER_STATUS = 1005;
const UINT_PTR ID_KEYBOARD_VOLTAGE = 1006;
const UINT_PTR ID_KEYBOARD_AMPS = 1007;
const UINT_PTR ID_FINGERPRINT_VOLTAGE = 1008;
const UINT_PTR ID_FINGERPRINT_AMPS = 1009;
const UINT_PTR ID_BARCODE_VOLTAGE = 1010;
const UINT_PTR ID_BARCODE_AMPS = 1011;
const UINT_PTR ID_HEADSET_VOLTAGE = 1012;
const UINT_PTR ID_HEADSET_AMPS = 1013;
const UINT_PTR ID_SPEAKER_VOLTAGE = 1014;
const UINT_PTR ID_SPEAKER_AMPS = 1015;

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

bool isWebcamAvailable() {
    VideoCapture cap(1);
    return cap.isOpened();
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    static VideoCapture cap;
    static Mat frame;
    static HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;

    switch (message) {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        int yPos = 10;
        const int yOffset = 40;
        const wchar_t* devices[] = { L"Webcam", L"Keyboard", L"Fingerprint Scanner", L"Barcode Scanner", L"Headset", L"Speaker Intercom" };

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            CreateWindowW(L"STATIC", (devices[i] + std::wstring(L" Status:")).c_str(), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 10, yPos, 180, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindowW(L"STATIC", L"Inactive", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 200, yPos, 80, 20, hWnd, reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(ID_WEBCAM_STATUS + i), NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindowW(L"STATIC", L"Voltage:", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 290, yPos, 60, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindowW(L"STATIC", L"0V", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 360, yPos, 50, 20, hWnd, reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(ID_KEYBOARD_VOLTAGE + i * 2), NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindowW(L"STATIC", L"Amps:", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 420, yPos, 50, 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            CreateWindowW(L"STATIC", L"0A", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 480, yPos, 50, 20, hWnd, reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(ID_KEYBOARD_AMPS + i * 2), NULL, NULL);
            yPos += yOffset;
        }

        // Create an area to display webcam image
        yPos += 10; // some spacing
        CreateWindowW(L"STATIC", NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_BITMAP, 10, yPos, 320, 240, hWnd, reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(ID_WEBCAM_IMAGE), NULL, NULL);

        // Initialize webcam capture
        cap.open(0);

        if (isWebcamAvailable()) {
            SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_WEBCAM_STATUS), L"Active");
        }
        else {
            SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_WEBCAM_STATUS), L"Inactive");
        }

        // Set a timer to periodically update the webcam image
        SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 100, NULL); // Update every 100 ms
    }
    break;

    case WM_TIMER:
    {
        if (cap.isOpened()) {
            cap >> frame;
            if (!frame.empty()) {
                if (hBitmap) DeleteObject(hBitmap);
                cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
                hBitmap = CreateBitmap(frame.cols, frame.rows, 1, 32, frame.data);
                SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_WEBCAM_IMAGE), STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);
                SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_WEBCAM_STATUS), L"Active");
            }
        }
        else {
            SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_WEBCAM_STATUS), L"Inactive");
        }
    }
    break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        cap.release();
        if (hBitmap) DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Device Status Window";

    WNDCLASS wc = {};

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        CLASS_NAME,
        L"BIT INPUT ELECTRICAL DEVICE INTERFACE",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 750, 500, // Adjust window size to accommodate all controls
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried changing the video feed resolution to see if it might be mismatched with the display area and also changed the values of the video capture index. Nothing worked.